# How to run a command without running cmd in Delphi

Tags: delphi, cmd

I want to run a command from Delphi. I can do it using `ShellExecute`.

This is how I do it:

```
 ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe', '/c start http://localhost/ ', nil, SW_HIDE);
```

But I want do this without using `cmd`.
Is there any way to do it?

I want to run below command as well:

```
ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe', '/c del RUNNING_PID', nil, SW_HIDE);
ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe', '/c .\bin\posonline-phm -Dhttp.port=80 -Dconfig.file=.\conf\application.conf ', nil, SW_HIDE);
```

Comment: What about using the [SO] search box? [delphi+start+browser+with+url](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=delphi+start+browser+with+url)

Comment: It didn't help me. I want run a command without using cmd. I gave only a one example. I have some other commands also. Anyway i will edit the question.

Comment: If you wish to pass http://localhost/ to the shell with an appropriate verb, that is possible. Is this the only form of command?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No. There are some other commands. I have edited the question.

Comment: "del" is a command, and cmd is the command interpreter. No can do.

Comment: You can't use a command that is executed by the command interpreter without using the command interpreter, period. The only thing that can run `start` or  `del` is `cmd.exe`. Your question is like *How can I use my fingers without my hand being involved?*, and the clear answer is *You can't*. If you don't want to use cmd, then don't use `del` or `start`.

Comment: Isn't `start` a wrapper around `ShellExecute` itself? If I recall correctly, `ShellExecute(0, nil, 'http://localhost/', nil, nil, SW_HIDE);` should be quasi equal in function...

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to perform some of your tasks without invoking cmd but not all. For instance `del` is a built in command of the cmd interpreter and therefore needs to be interpreted by cmd.

Of course, you don't need to get cmd to execute `del` in order to delete a file. That is trivially easy using the API provided by the operating system. So it's quite possible that you can avoid cmd if you wish.

Comment: Okay. i will do delete without using cmd. Is there way to do others without cmd?

Comment: For the first one pass the URL to ShellExecute or ShellExecuteEx. The other one appears to be starting a new process. That's CreateProcess.